# If I'm instrument current in an ASEL, am I also considered current in an AMEL?

Tags: faa-regulations, currency

[FAR §61.57(c)(1)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=14:2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_157):

> Within the 6 calendar months preceding . . . logged at least the
> following tasks and iterations in an airplane, powered-lift,
> helicopter, or airship, as appropriate . . .

I would infer from this that 1) instrument currency does NOT carry over from one category to another but 2) that it does carry over from one class to another within a category. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you maintain instrument currency by category, not class. 61.57(c) only mentions class in the glider-specific requirements in (c)(3). The FAA doesn't mention it at all in related legal interpretations.

Note this wording from 61.57(c)(2) (emphasis mine):

> A pilot may accomplish the requirements in paragraph (c)(1) of this
> section in a full flight simulator, flight training device, or
> aviation training device provided the device represents the **category**
> of aircraft for the instrument rating privileges to be maintained and
> the pilot performs the tasks and iterations in simulated instrument
> conditions. A person may complete the instrument experience in any
> combination of an aircraft, full flight simulator, flight training
> device, or aviation training device.

See also [this legal interpretation, Griffith (2008)](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2008/griffith%20-%20(2008)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> Generally, all appropriate endorsements for passing the instrument
> proficiency check, which would be otherwise given if the check were
> passed in an aircraft, can also be given when one passes the check by
> using an FTD, as long as the FTD represents the appropriate aircraft
> **category** for the instrument privileges sought.

It's true that you have to pass an instrument checkride (or at least some specific tasks) in a class before you can exercise those privileges in that class, but that's a one-time thing that doesn't affect how you maintain currency. See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/57715/62) for more details.